# Protection threshold not in use

Tags: bug, status-norepro, protected-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17467539/1091386 was posted by a user with 1 reputation even though the question had been protected. This feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They had 11 reputation at the time when the answer was posted, so the threshold's (likely) still working as intended.

Comment: How come he had 11 rep? [He had 4 questions with 1 downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2294910/mahdy), and nothing else. He doesn't seem to have any suggested edits or anything. Did he happen to have a deleted upvoted question/answer?

Comment: @Antony A deleted answer with one upvote.